# Scaffold error: This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm switching from flutter to compose and i'm creating my first app with compose. But there is one problem, components i used in flutter, i can't make them work in compose. Especially Scaffold and TopAppBar.

I have tried almost everything, passing some experimental api arguments to compiler, the official articles, some Github templates... but it still causes the same error `This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.`
Also I'm trying to make the app bar in material 3 but all the previews on the articles seems to have still the material 2 which i am not sure if it's what i need. *note: in flutter everything worked well*

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SimpleTodoApkaTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar {
                            Text(text = "My todo app")
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Hello, world!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)` above the class

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You can use a Box, Column or whatever composable you like.  Material3 wants you to use the padding values which can add padding to the top bottom or sides. It's customizable.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SimpleTodoApkaTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = { Text("My todo app") }
                        )
                    },
                    content = { paddingValues ->
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
                        )
                        {
                            Text("Hello, world!")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```